# Splitter/Aggregator with fire/forget and timeout

Tags: apache-camel

We have a splitter process which pushes messages to different queues. There's another process which collects and aggregates these messages for further processing.

We want to have a timeout between the moment of splitting and being aggregated.
IIUC aggregation timeout starts with the first message and is it being reset after every aggregated message (it is interval based, not for the complete message).

What's the best solution to solve this?

Comment: So, you want the aggregator to assume that a particular aggregation is complete if NNNN seconds have elapsed since the message was split? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, the total time time of splitting and aggregating a "messagebundle" may not take more than NNNN seconds.

Comment: Oh,  I completely misunderstood the question then - I thought you wanted to delay the aggregation for a while - I was completely off the mark.

Comment: The closest thing I could think of would be to use `completionInterval` instead of `completionTimeout` and perhaps see if it can be combined with a completion predicate; I'll give it a try tomorrow if someone else doesn't figure it out in the meantime.

Comment: We've been thinking about sending some kind of dummy notification-message to the aggregator-queue which will start counting for the timeout. But there's still the issue of the resetting of the timeout with every new message, though.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Here's the best I was able to come up with, although it's a bit of a hack. First, you save a timestamp as a message header and publish it to the queue with the body:

```
from("somewhere")
    .split(body())
    .process(e -> e.getIn().setHeader("aggregation_timeout", 
        ZonedDateTime.now().plusSeconds(COMPLETION_TIMEOUT)))
    .to("aggregation-route-uri");
```

Then, when consuming and aggregating, you use a custom aggregation strategy that will save the `aggregation_timeout` from the first message in the current  group and then use a `completionPredicate` that reads that value to check whether the timeout has expired (alternatively, if you're aggregating in a way that keeps the message ordering intact, you could just read the header from the first message). Use a short `completionTimeout` as a safeguard for cases when the interval between two messages is long:

```
from("aggregation-route-uri")
    .aggregate(bySomething())
    .aggregationStrategy((oldExchange, newExchange) -> {
      // read aggregation_timeout header from first message 
      // and set it as property in grouped exchange
      // perform aggregation
    })
    .completionTimeout(1000) // intentionally low value, here as a safeguard
    .completionPredicate(e -> {
      // complete once the timeout has been reached
      return e.getProperty("aggregation_timeout", ZonedDateTime.class)
              .isAfter(ZonedDateTime.now());
    })
    .process(e -> // do something with aggregates);
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that splitter and aggregator both have their own CamelContext because we expect a huge amount of messages and long running tasks by external systems. Aggregation information is persisted. I don't think the suggested solution will work with separated CamelContexts, right?

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't work, it's context-agnostic

Comment: There's still the issue in case a message bundle only contains one message. Such a message should also be handled (error processing) when a timeout occurs. At least this confirms there's no out-of-the-box pattern yet.

Comment: Doesn't completionTimeout handle the single-message scenario? If the bundle contained only a single message, it will be aggregated after a second

Comment: The splitted message will be put on a queue and it depends on the third party how fast it can process that message and reply on our aggregator-queue. If this takes too much time, the messagebundle should timeout.

Comment: Yeah, in that case I think you're better with a fully custom solution - something along the lines with the approach you took first: send the message when you start splitting and then write custom code that reads (i. e. polls) from the aggregation queue and timeouts after your desired timeout.